# CURL not working from PHP but it does from command line

Tags: php, curl

I'm calling a URL of this kind:

> http://localhost:9910/app/check?name=alvaro&test=true

Accessing through the browser URL I get the correct result. And the same when using the command line with `curl`, it retrieves the correct information:

```
C:\>curl "http://localhost:9910/boxreload/check?name=alvaro&test=true" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-length: 203
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.3.3
Accept-ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 18:01:30 GMT

{"restul": "true"}
```

But when doing it with PHP it never comes back from the `curl_exec` and the server times out after 30 seconds.

```
$stringData =  http_build_query($data);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, $stringData);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    array(
    'Content-Type: application/json;',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($stringData))
);

// $url is "'http://localhost:9910/boxreload/check?name=alvaro&test=true'"
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//never comes back from this call (server times out)
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_response === FALSE){
    echo "error en CURL";
    echo curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);

//never reaches this point
print_r($curl_response);
```

Why is it? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You `echo` nothing. What did you expect?

Comment: @u_mulder my point is, the server times out on `curl_exec`... never coming back. I don't echo anything in this example because it is not necessary for my question.

Comment: try to add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 9910);`

Comment: @Slam nothing. Same.

Comment: why the `Content-` headers ? They don't mean anything on a get request (since there is no body).

Comment: add `print_r(curl_getinfo());` before `curl_close($curl);`

Comment: Also check your `$url` value, it valid after using `sprintf(…)`?

Comment: @Meroje it is a simplified example... my code has actually PUT and POST.

Comment: change the `print_r` in the last line to echo and are you sure what you're connecting to requires the client to send the `'Content-Type: application/json' and 'Content-Length:  nnn'` headers? Because if they're supposed to be response headers, then don't send those headers as part of the request.

Comment: @Slam it doesn't reach any point after `curl_exec`.

Comment: You could set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to avoid being stuck (doesn't solve but you can handle the failure)

Comment: Do you have `curl_init()`?

Comment: @Mike it seems you are right. I removed the HTTPHEADER lines and it worked as expected. Please add it as an answer with a better explanation of it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I'm turning my comment into an answer.

change the print_r in the last line to echo so that you can see the raw string output.

This code fragment:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    array(
'Content-Type: application/json;',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($stringData))
);
```

means you're sending these headers to the server when making the request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: nnn
```

where nnn is an integer representing the length of `$stringData`.

Just make sure the proper headers are sent when making the request or you will likely receive undesired results. It is unusual to specify the content-type and content-length as headers being passed from client to server. It should be the other way around (where server sends to the client the content-type and content-length header).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do curl_init

`$curl = curl_init();`

and your if statement has a missing $ in front of the variable.
check this code:

```
$data = [];

$stringData =  http_build_query($data);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", "http://google.ro/", $stringData);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    array(
    'Content-Type: application/json;',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($stringData))
);

// $url is "'http://localhost:9910/boxreload/check?name=alvaro&test=true'"
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//never comes back from this call (server times out)
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

if($curl_response === FALSE){
    echo "error en CURL";
    echo curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);

//never reaches this point
print_r($curl_response);
```